# How to check if a field can be left blank in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have simple ModelForm. Some of those fields can be left blank. In the template I'd like to let the user know which fields are required (not to be left blank) and which are not required (can be left blank). How to do that?

This did not work:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {% if field.blank %} * {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a field is [**`blank=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#blank) in the model, the counterpart in the form has [**`required=False`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#required).

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {% if not field.field.required %} * {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```